# Append the value of argLine param in maven-surefire-plugin

Tags: java, maven, maven-3, maven-surefire-plugin

I am using `maven-surefire-plugin` + `Sonar` together and I would like to add some extra value to `argLine` parameter of the maven-surefire-plugin.

So I did it:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.20.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <argLine>-DCRR.Webservice.isSimulated=true -D...</argLine>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        ...
    </plugins>
</build>
```

But in this case I am overwriting the original value of the `argLine` parameter and Sonar does not generate jacoco.exec file.

I can see in the maven debug log (-X) that the value of argLine param without overwriting its value is `-javaagent:/opt/jenkins/.../myproject-SONAR/.repository/org/jacoco/org.jacoco.agent/0.7.4.201502262128/org.jacoco.agent-0.7.4.201502262128-runtime.jar=destfile=/opt/jenkins/.../myproject-SONAR/target/jacoco.exec`.

What is the proper way to APPEND the original value of this parameter (keep the original + add extra values)?

I am using Apache Maven 3.5.0, Java version: 1.8.0_131, vendor: Oracle Corporation.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The official documentation calls that [late replacement](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#argLine).

If you do the following you will overwrite the value of the `argLine` parameter which is set by another plugins before, so **DO NOT DO THIS:**

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <argLine>-D... -D...</argLine>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

The proper way to keep the existing values and add your configuration is to use `@{...}` syntax:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <argLine>@{argLine} -D... -D...</argLine>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

OR you can set `argLine` as a `property` in your `pom.xml` file:

```
<properties>
    <argLine>-DCRR.Webservice.isSimulated=true -D...</argLine>
</properties>
```

Both solutions above works properly.

Comment: I don't see where is "APPEND the original value" in your solution

Comment: That is the way how you can APPEND that value. Define argLine as a property instead of add it directly to the plugin.

Comment: When I read "APPEND", I expect in one place "-Dfoo=bar" in second place "-Dalpha=beta" and there is a way to get "-Dfoo=bar -Dalpha=beta". You described how to REPLACE, not how to APPEND. Moreover, you wrote "Do not define argLine between the <configuration> tags:". Why not? User property "argLine" precedes plugin property "argLine". Maybe your answer is correct, but please provide concrete example: default configuration with jacoco and solution how to add "some extra value" and preserve jacoco settings. What I see now is only moving "argLine" from plugin configuration to build property.

Comment: That is an APPEND. Have you checked the official documentation? It says : "late replacement". http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#argLine

Comment: I'm confused, maybe I misundestand something. Could you increase answer readability. For example, a paragraph starts with "Do not define argLine .." and below is snippet with "<argLine>...</argLine>". Is the snippet positive or negative example? I think the best solution is more concrete answer, with sample jacoco setting and way to add extra value. Moreover, your mention in comment about "late replacement" but your answer does not use syntax @{}

Comment: I still have some problem with the solution. I applied the solution and I got error reported in https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SUREFIRE-1431. The JIRA issue is resolved by as not-a-bug, but I don't understand answer. Zappee, is your solution working only together with jacoco plugin?

Comment: I do not use jacoco plugin, sorry.

Comment: I can also confirm that ${argline} also worked for me.  I wonder if newer versions of Maven changed the behaviour of ${...}?

Answer (score 12):

**Update** for `Apache Maven 3.8.3`.

In my case only combination of both @zapee suggestions works, in other words it's important to add `<argLine/>` to `<properties>` and `@{argLine}` to configuration section. Example:

```xml
<properties>
  <!--  This is required for later correct replacement of argline -->
  <argLine/>
</properties>
...
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
  <configuration>
    <argLine>@{argLine} -D... -D...</argLine> 
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Hope, it helps somebody.

Answer (score 1):

There's a difference between using ${} and @{}.

`${}` is used by maven to do property replacement, which is done before any plugin is run.

`@{}` is used by the maven surefire plugin as of Version 2.17 and allows for "late replacement" of properties when the the surefire plugin is executed,  so properties that have been modified by other plugins will be picked up correctly.

[reference](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/faq.html#late-property-evaluation)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks!

In my case it was:

```
<argLine>${tycho.testArgLine} -D...</argLine>
```