# SonarQube: Please provide compiled classes of your project

Tags: java, sonarqube

I am running Sonar Qube 6.5 and using Sonar scanner 3.0.3.

When I run sonar-scanner for my projects, I encountered the error as below:

```
ERROR: Error during SonarQube Scanner execution
org.sonar.squidbridge.api.AnalysisException: Please provide compiled classes of your project with sonar.java.binaries property
        at org.sonar.java.JavaClasspath.init(JavaClasspath.java:59)
        at org.sonar.java.AbstractJavaClasspath.getElements(AbstractJavaClasspath.java:281)
        at org.sonar.java.SonarComponents.getJavaClasspath(SonarComponents.java:141)
        at org.sonar.java.JavaSquid.<init>(JavaSquid.java:83)
        at org.sonar.plugins.java.JavaSquidSensor.execute(JavaSquidSensor.java:83)
        at org.sonar.scanner.sensor.SensorWrapper.analyse(SensorWrapper.java:53)
        at org.sonar.scanner.phases.SensorsExecutor.executeSensor(SensorsExecutor.java:88)
        at org.sonar.scanner.phases.SensorsExecutor.execute(SensorsExecutor.java:82)
        at org.sonar.scanner.phases.SensorsExecutor.execute(SensorsExecutor.java:68)
        at org.sonar.scanner.phases.AbstractPhaseExecutor.execute(AbstractPhaseExecutor.java:78)
        at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ModuleScanContainer.doAfterStart(ModuleScanContainer.java:179)
        at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:144)
        at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:129)
        at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scan(ProjectScanContainer.java:261)
        at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(ProjectScanContainer.java:256)
        at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.doAfterStart(ProjectScanContainer.java:245)
        at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:144)
        at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:129)
        at org.sonar.scanner.task.ScanTask.execute(ScanTask.java:47)
        at org.sonar.scanner.task.TaskContainer.doAfterStart(TaskContainer.java:84)
        at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:144)
        at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:129)
        at org.sonar.scanner.bootstrap.GlobalContainer.executeTask(GlobalContainer.java:119)
        at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.executeTask(Batch.java:116)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.batch.BatchIsolatedLauncher.execute(BatchIsolatedLauncher.java:63)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherProxy.invoke(IsolatedLauncherProxy.java:60)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.execute(Unknown Source)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.doExecute(EmbeddedScanner.java:233)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.runAnalysis(EmbeddedScanner.java:151)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.runAnalysis(Main.java:123)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.execute(Main.java:77)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.main(Main.java:61)

ERROR:
ERROR: Re-run SonarQube Scanner using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the way you can use your own sonar, installed on localhost:

1. Download SonarQube from [here](https://sonarsource.bintray.com/Distribution)
2. Unpack
3. Refresh the Java Plugin, you can download the plugin from [here](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/SonarJava)

> In the page dedicated to the plugin you want to install (ex: for Python : SonarPython), click on the "Download" link of the version compatible with your SonarQube version. Upload the downloaded jar file in your SonarQube Server and put it in the directory: $SONARQUBE_HOME/extensions/plugins.If another version of the same plugin is already there, you need to remove it, since only one version of a given plugin may be available in the extensions/plugins directory.

4. Start SonarQube: <SONAR_HOME>\bin\windows-x86-64\StartSonar.bat
5. Login to SonarQube

- Url: http://localhost:9000/
- Credentials: admin/admin

6. Check the Java Plugin version: visit Administration > System > Update Center > SonarJava menu
7. Execute the following maven task, it generates code quality and code coverage report as well:

> mvn -e -B org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.2:sonar
> -Dsonar.host.url=http://localhost:9000

8. Code coverage report

You can find more details about code coverage plugin configuration [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46489455/append-the-value-of-argline-param-in-maven-surefire-plugin/46490011#46490011).

Comment: Hi,
I use Sonar Scanner to run the Sonar Qube.