# How to set default TimeZone for Maven Java build on Jenkins?

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, timezone

We are running Jenkins on server with UTC but our office is located at Berlin. Thus we configured `-Dorg.apache.commons.jelly.tags.fmt.timeZone=Europe/Berlin` to have the UI in CE(S)T.

But how to ensure Maven Java builds to run with default TimeZone Europe/Berlin?

We tried to add `-Duser.timezone=Europe/Berlin`to the Jenkins scipt and to Global MAVEN_OPTS.

But `TimeZone.getDefault()` (in jUnit tests) results in `sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="GMT",offset=0,dstSavings=0,useDaylight=false,transitions=0,lastRule=null]`.

Comment: Did you see this thread : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23466218/setting-timezone-for-maven-unit-tests-on-java-8

Comment: Yes, adding `<argLine>-Duser.timezone=Europe/Berlin</argLine>` works as desired. But I prefer configuring Jenkins than modifying the code.

Comment: You should use late replacement to set surefire argLine from Jenkins:
https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/faq.html#late-property-evaluation

See this thread : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46489455/append-the-value-of-argline-param-in-maven-surefire-plugin/46490011