# SonarQube Reading Becomes 0 after upgrading from Java 8 to 11

Tags: spring-boot, sonarqube, jacoco, maven-surefire-plugin, jacoco-maven-plugin

I recently upgraded my project from Java 8 to 11. For the dependency of Jacoco, i upgraded *jacoco-maven-plugin* from version **0.7.6.201602180812** to **0.8.7**

After that, my Sonar code coverage becomes 0. Below is a part of my pom.xml related to my jacoco build and pluginmanagement

[Build Plugins](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bBLwS.png)

[pluginManagement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M4zwg.png)

I keep on changing the Jacoco version, thinking that I'm not using the best version for Java 11 that's why the Sonar report are not generated, but still failed to resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

- Try changing ${argLine} to @{argLine}, this format allows for late replacement of properties in surefire. This might be the fix for Java 11, JaCoCo and surefire compatibility. Read about late replacement and JaCoCo [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46489455/append-the-value-of-argline-param-in-maven-surefire-plugin)
- Try downgrading JaCoCo to version 0.8.3. In my experience Java 11 was not compatible with any version above 0.8.3.

Comment: I already did the above possible fixes, but nothing works in my case. Even in my local, I can see that test are seem not being scanned after mvn clean install command:

Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

Comment: @Oragon what other plugins are you using? it's hard to know why your tests would be skipped without more information. for example if you're using spring boot, and an older version of junit, you would need the junit-vintage-engine plugin. but that's a specific case